# How do i move my question to a different SE?

Tags: support, migration

I've asked a question and after a couple of days thinking on it (and seeing low viewing) I suspect I might get better/faster results by moving it to Unix SE.

So how do I do this or request this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'm not encouraging moving a question to another stack site.

So if you want it moved and you don't have any answers yet you can just delete it.

If you have answers, you can flag it so the mods see it.  Use the custom flag and say why you think it would receive a better response on UL.